# Amazon MWS Product API's How to tell whether x-pack watermark shows on product image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I am trying to figure out what makes the x pack watermark on product image to show up.
I am using Product API's GetMatchingProduct to get ItemAttributes for an ASIN.

For this ASIN B0030J5IFK, it has NumberOfItems : 4 and it has the 4-pack watermark on the product image.
However, when I checked a few other ASINs that also have NumberOfItems more than 1, but it does not have the x-pack watermark on the product image. For example ASIN B00J6FR2RY has NumberOfItems : 4 and no watermark.

Is there any other attribute that contributes to determine whether the x-pack watermark would show?
Note: Both ASINs has PackageQuantity: 1.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the examples listed above show the watermark when I pull them up but I think I know what you are looking for.

Take a look at ASIN B01CM42JBO.

You will see that the 2 pack watermark is there.

When you GetMatchingProduct with ASIN B01CM42JBO you will notice the following.

```
 <ns2:NumberOfItems>4</ns2:NumberOfItems>
 <ns2:PackageQuantity>2</ns2:PackageQuantity>
```

In your examples the PackageQuantity is 1 for both. The Package Quantity is what determines if the watermark is applied.